# Haskell Bool to Char function seems to have the wrong type

Tags: haskell

The following (very easy) code seems to have a type definition problem

```
BoolToChar :: Bool -> Char
BoolToChar False = '0'
BoolToChar True = '1'
```

I don't see my mistake.

Comment: `'0'` and `'1'` are not integers. The single quotes mean treat this as a character. `7` is an integer, `'7'` isn't for the same reason `'a'` or `'£'` isn't.

Comment: @Cubic No claim was made that `'0'` or `'1'` are integers.

Comment: @DanielWagner The title is calling this a "Bool to Int" function

Comment: Hah! So it does. I'll fix it up to match the body of the question.

Comment: @Cubic I know, I want to map every bool value to the character of it's value. (It's only an auxiliary function, I have a list of bools and want to map this list to a string which represents this list in the canonical way.) **EDIT:** Sorry, title was just a typo

Comment: Be sure to search SO for the error you get (and try to post it in your question); most of these sorts of gotchas have been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 10):

Variable names must start with lower-case letters (or non-`:` symbols if they are infix names), so that the compiler can easily distinguish them from constructors.

Comment: Ok, I understand my problem. Thanks! Do you have any idea how to fix that? It's pretty obvious what these function should do...

Comment: @Dominik Yes, I have an idea how to fix that: use a name that starts with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 9):

Functions must start with a lowercase letter. Uppercase is treated as a data constructor.